# How i can import LESS CSS in .net?

Tags: html, css, less

i want to use Google font in my own web page when i write on the top in LESS CSS File

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kelly+Slab);
```

i got the error that

```
Illegal characters in path.
```

can someone tell me how i can use them in less css in my own asp.net project

Comment: Not really clear. Can you explain more? Are you using ASP.NET MVC? Does Google return error message? What all this has to do with [Less CSS](http://lesscss.org)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using single quotes around the actual url

```
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kelly+Slab');
```